# Cakephp 4 Naming conventions policies singular/plural

Tags: cakephp, model, naming-conventions

I have a few basic applications in Cake now. I am adding authorizations to define who can do that. I have installed the Authenticate and Autorize modules. Now I am setting up the "policies". I got some error messages and noticed a bit of a discrepancy. Let's say we are baking a model for cookies. I would have a table "cookies". I can then bake the code with the following command line;

```
cake bake all cookies
```

This does not bake the policy, so I would do this separately as well;

```
cake bake policy cookies
```

However, this does not work. If I tell the CookiesController that authorization has to be checked on the current model, it tries to find the "CookiePolicy". However, the bake command has createed the "CookiesPolicy". I would have to bake "policy cookie". That seems a little inconistent to me. Did I miss something? Any thoughts?

Comment: The singular name is most likely correct, please show what resource exactly you are checking, "_the current model_" is a little vague.

Comment: current model in the context of what I wrote is the model of the Cookies. More specifically; check whether the user has been authorised to execute a certain function on the controller.

Comment: That would still be too vague, people throw around the term model a lot, sometimes refering to query objects, sometimes to table objects, sometimes to entity objects, and sometimes to the whole model layer. The looked up policy depends on the type of object that you're checking, if you're talking about models, and the policy being looked up is singular like `CookiePolicy`, then this would suggest that you've likely checked against an entity. But that's just guessing, hence why I've asked for details.

Answer (score 2):

It's not inconsistent pluralization - the two commands take different arguments.

The `bake all` command expects a *database table name* - by convention Tables should be plural.

The `bake policy` command policy can take *either* an Entity name, Table name, or generic object name -- but **defaults to an Entity**, per the help, it has a `--type` argument:

```
$ cake bake policy --help
Bake policy classes for various supported object types.

Usage:
cake bake policy [options] [<name>]

Options:
 ...
--type            The object type to bake a policy for. If only one
                  argument is used, type will be object.
                  (default: entity)
                  (choices: table|entity|object)
                  (required)
 ...
```

Your command is baking an Entity policy, those are singular. If you want to bake a Table policy, you'll have to specify the type manually and use the plural Table name, per conventions:

```
$ cake bake policy cookies --type=table

Creating file /var/www/html/src/Policy/CookiesTablePolicy.php
Wrote `/var/www/html/src/Policy/CookiesTablePolicy.php`
```

Comment: That's very well explained, thank you. I had not realised that yet.